# Mongodb find near maxdistance

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, mongodb-query

I am firing the following query in mongodb

```
db.acollection.find({
    "field.location": {
        "$near": [19.0723058, 73.00067739999997]
    }, 
    $maxDistance : 100000
}).count()
```

and getting the following error -

```
uncaught exception: count failed: {
    "shards" : {

    },
    "cause" : {
        "errmsg" : "exception: unknown top level operator: $maxDistance",
        "code" : 2,
        "ok" : 0
    },
    "code" : 2,
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "failed on : Shard ShardA"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did it wrong. The [**`$maxDistance`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/maxDistance/#op._S_maxDistance) argument is a "child" of the [**`$near`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) operator:

```js
db.acollection.find({
    "field.location": {
        "$near": [19.0723058, 73.00067739999997],
        "$maxDistance": 100000
    }
}).count()
```

Has to be within the same expression.

Also look at GeoJSON when you are making a new application. It is the way you should be storing in the future.